# How do I get Nginx to pass an external DNS name when reverse proxying?

Tags: nginx, dns

I'm trying to use Nginx wrap a somewhat poorly documented and temperamental API hosted by one of our clients. Despite my best efforts, I can't quite get Nginx to transform the inbound format of the request we want to make (a GET request with the two parameters as URL parameters) into what we need to submit to this API (a POST request with a request body that encodes the arguments as a JSON blob).

I have a working call to this API in Python code, but I can't figure out what I'm failing to do in the Nginx setup to replicate the behavior. The idea here is to offload wrapping this request from slow Python code to Nginx.

The Python code looks something like this:

```
REMOTE_URI = 'https://api.mycompany.com/services/some/api/endpoint/here/'

async def get_promotion_data(customer_id, product_id):
    params = {'AccountNumber': customer_id,
              'ProductIdentifier': product_id}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(REMOTE_URI,
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                data=json.dumps(params)) as response:

            data = await response.json()

            if not data:
                return {}

            return data
```

And my best attempt at getting this to work in Nginx is:

```
location /internal/wrapper {
    proxy_set_header   Host      api.mycompany.com;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_connect_timeout 100ms;
    proxy_read_timeout 5s;
    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_set_body '{"AccountNumber":"${arg_customer_id}","ProductIdentifier":"${arg_product_id}"}';
    proxy_set_header X-Content-Type application/json;
    proxy_pass https://api.mycompany.com/services/some/api/endpoint/here/;
}
```

Yet when I call the Nginx wrapped version, it always returns a 504, that the connection to the upstream timed out. (I've tried upping the proxy timeouts in Nginx; the API we're connecting to is pretty fast, so that's almost definitely not the issue.)

My best guess from playing around with the API we're calling directly with tools like `curl` is that something on our client's end is routing based on the hostname in the URL. When I try doing `curl "https://api.mycompany.com/services/some/api/endpoint/here/"` it returns a response that suggests I'm hitting the right server. When I do `curl "https://123.123.123.123/services/some/api/endpoint/here/"` I get a bunch of redirects somewhere else.

It also appears that Nginx is resolving the domain and calling the IP directly rather than passing the hostname explicitly. In the `error.log` file it's logging that the upstream it tried (and timed out against) is `123.123.123.123` rather than `api.mycompany.com`. This is also why I tried adding the `Host` header as part of the proxy pass.

Maybe I've missed something else? Is there another way to tell Nginx how to deal with a hostname when proxying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there were a couple of mistakes here. First, the header for the JSON content type was `Content-Type` rather than `X-Content-Type`. More importantly, I needed to add `proxy_ssl_server_name on` to the configuration. Turns out I was right about the hostname being an issue here, and that the real issue was due to Nginx not sending the server name when making an HTTPs request.